# setOnItemSelectedListener context

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

First of all thank you for reading.

**What I am doing:**

I am getting data from a server and I am trying to show this data on a spinner. The problem is that I had to move all network connections to threads so I need to wait until I get this data to put it on the spinner.

I am using a handler to once I got all data charge it on the spinner.

**The problem:**

When I use setOnItemSelectedListener() on onCreate I simply use the the Activity´s context using "**this**" but on the handler I am trying to use the activity's context but keeps asking me for

*"The method setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) in the type AdapterView is not applicable for the arguments (Context)"*

- Is it right what I am trying to do?
- How can I setOnItemSelectedListener from the handler?

**The code:**

```
private Handler puentePais = new Handler() {
      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterPais = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, listaPaisesString);

        spPais = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spPais);
        spPais.setAdapter(dataAdapterPais);
        spPais.setPrompt("Seleccione un pais");
        spPais.setOnItemSelectedListener([WHAT SHOULD I USE HERE?]);

      spPais.setSelection(posPais);

  }
 };
```

Regards!

Comment: Implement the interface OnItemSelectedListener in your activity, then it will work.

Comment: I did it and It works fine when I set the listener from onCreate. The problem is being to do it from the Handler.

Comment: just write "this" it will work.

Comment: I tried it. The problem was to use Context context = this; I changed for MyActivityClass context = this; and it work fine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MyActivity.this` instead of `this`.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is shorter. Now, as  Robin spent time trying to help I don´t see why downvoting him.. Regards!

Comment: Voting is there to rank answers.